# Set window.location.protocol in different browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I try to switch the protocol and reload the page via

```
 window.location.protocol = 'https:';
```

I use `https:` with a colon instead of `http` because when I type `window.location.protocol` in the console, it prints with colon.

But now I found that the code above is not working on Firefox 40, I was told to remove the colon. And I found that the code below has better compatibility, it works on chrome and ff, even FF40 which is not working before.

```
 window.location.protocol = 'https';
```

To be honest, it's really strange when you set a property with value `https`, then you get an `https:`.

My question is: is it a bug of FF40, or my second line of code is the standard way to switch protocol?

Answer (score 1):

window.location.protocol is not writeable, only readable, meaning you cannot change the value.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it dynamically,by testing how the browser return the protocol of the current URL like this:

```
if(location.protocol.slice(-1)==":")
{ 
  window.location.protocol = 'https:'
  }
else
{  
  window.location.protocol = 'https'

}
```